# AdxStudio CrmEntityFormView Swallowing Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.SaveChangesException

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I posted this on the AdxStudio forum and got exactly zero response, so I'm hoping ya'll can help me debug this.

I'm using a CrmEntityFormView to create a new contact in CRM, like so:

```xml
<adx:CrmDataSource ID="FormViewDataSource" runat="server" />
    <adx:CrmEntityFormView runat="server" ID="UserCreateForm" EntityName="contact" FormName="User Edit Form" DataSourceID="FormViewDataSource"
        RecommendedFieldsRequired="true" ValidationGroup="NewUser" ValidationText="* This field is required" EnableValidationSummaryLinks="false" 
        OnItemInserting="UserCreateForm_ItemInserting" OnItemInserted="UserCreateForm_ItemInserted">
        <InsertItemTemplate></InsertItemTemplate>
</adx:CrmEntityFormView>

<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" Text='Create User' CssClass="button" ValidationGroup="NewUser" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
```

I'm using the SubmitButton_Click handler to handle some other fields on the form at the same time like so:

```cs
 protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!Page.IsValid)
        {
            return;
        }

    # Handle other form fields not on the FormView ...
    UserCreateForm.InsertItem();
 }
```

Nothing happens in my database when I submit a valid form. So I debugged the ItemInserted event, putting a breakpoint on the single line of the handler

```cs
    protected void UserCreateForm_ItemInserted(object sender, CrmEntityFormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
    {
        Contact newUser = XrmContext.ContactSet.Where(c => c.ContactId == e.EntityId).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Turns out, in this event, e.Exception is not null, but an instance of the SaveChangesException from the title, with the message "An error occured while processing this request." and e.ExceptionHandled == true, which I guess is why I never saw anything.

This exception has an InnerException, an instance of `System.ServiceModel.FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>`

with a message that always just contains the submitted value of the first field in the FormView. I have absolutely no idea why this isn't working, and I'm unclear how to debug this further and can use some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.ServiceModel.FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>` eats the stack trace.  Refer to [this blog](http://www.dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-prevent-faultexception-from.html) as a method to actually log the stacktrace to be able to find where your error is occurring.